# Целевой тип лямбда-выражения

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Что называется **целевым типом** лямбда-выражения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Источник](https://.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/28001133/)

> Целевым типом лямбда-выражения называется **тип контекста**, в котором это
>   выражение встречается, – например, **тип локальной переменной**, которой оно
>   присваивается, или **тип параметра метода**, вместо которого оно передается.